# Refit v6.x 'utf8' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: c#, refit

[Refit 6 makes `System.Text.Json` the default JSON serializer](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#breaking-changes-in-6x), After I upgraded to v6.x, an exception occurred：

```
Refit.ApiException: An error occured deserializing the response.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The character set provided in ContentType is invalid.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: 'utf8' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. (Parameter 'name')
   at System.Text.EncodingTable.InternalGetCodePageFromName(String name)
   at System.Text.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String name)
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(String name)
   at System.Net.Http.Json.JsonContent.GetEncoding(String charset)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.Json.JsonContent.GetEncoding(String charset)
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync[T](HttpContent content, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Refit.SystemTextJsonContentSerializer.FromHttpContentAsync[T](HttpContent content, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/Refit/SystemTextJsonContentSerializer.cs:line 63
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.DeserializeContentAsync[T](HttpResponseMessage resp, HttpContent content, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 324
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.DeserializeContentAsync[T](HttpResponseMessage resp, HttpContent content, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 330
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 277
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   ...
```

Response header looks like `content-type: text/html; charset=utf8`

I don't have permission to modify `utf8` to `utf-8`, and I want to use `System.Text.Json` instead of `Newtonsoft.Json`

Use the following code to get a similar exception

```cs
Encoding.GetEncoding("utf8");
```

Similar issue: https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/336

Answer (score 3):

#### Create a EncodingProvider

```cs
    sealed class MyEncodingProvider : EncodingProvider
    {
        public override Encoding GetEncoding(int codepage)
        {
            return CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(codepage);
        }

        public override Encoding GetEncoding(string name)
        {
            if (name == "utf8")
            {
                return Encoding.UTF8;
            }
            else
            {
                return CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(name);
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Register custom EncodingProvider

```cs
Encoding.RegisterProvider(new MyEncodingProvider());
```